# kullback leibler divergence of empirical density and fitted density in R

Tags: r, entropy

I have a vector and I used Pareto and Log-normal distribution to get a predicted density function. I am wondering is there any easy ways to calculate the KLD between the true distribution and fitted distribution?

I guess I may need a discrete form, though the fitted density is continuous?

Below is the graph of my data and fitted distributions.

[image]

Comment: I believe the KLD (or relative entropy) of those two distributions will be infinity. The reason is that the fitted distribution is continuous, while the empirical distribution is discrete. Why would you like to compute KLD between those distributions anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To calculate the KLD estimate between the log-normal distribution and the Pareto distribution with respect to the empirical distribution, you must turn them into discrete values. The definition of the KLD in discrete form is

$$D_{KL}(P||Q) = \sum_i p(i) \log \frac{p(i)}{q(i)} $$

where ***P*** represents the true distribution and ***Q*** represents the theoretical distribution. In an essence, it is about the average information gained based on a prior ***Q***.

To do such a task in R, I used the following code:

```
library(fitdistrplus); library(actuar); library(VGAM)
set.seed(123456)
a     <- rexp(1000, 0.25)
coefs <-coef(fitdist(a, 'lnorm'))
lnorm <- dlnorm(seq(min(a),max(a), by = .001), meanlog = coefs[1], sdlog = coefs[2])
coefp <- coef(fitdist(a, 'pareto', start = list(shape = 1, scale = 1)))
paretox<- dpareto(seq(min(a),max(a), by = .001), coefp[1], coefp[2])
h  <- hist(a, breaks = 30, freq = F, ylim = c(0,.35), xlim = c(0, 30))
lines(seq(min(a),max(a), by = .001), lnorm, col = 'blue', lwd = 3)
lines(seq(min(a),max(a), by = .001), paretox,col = 'darkgreen',lwd = 3)

pln <- dlnorm(h$mids, coefs[1], coefs[2])
ppar<- dpareto(h$mids, coefp[1], coefp[2])
trus<- h$density
pln <- pln[which(trus>0)]; ppar <- ppar[which(trus>0)]
trus<- trus[which(trus>0)]
KLD_lnorm <- sum(trus*log10(trus/pln))
KLD_pareto<- sum(trus*log10(trus/ppar))

> KLD_pareto
[1] 0.005314876
> KLD_lnorm
[1] 0.0150227
```

The code above first creates an exponential random variable `a` and the finds the `lnorm` or log-normal coefficients used in the `dlnorm` function. Then the program finds the coefficients of the pareto function, `scale` and `shape` as used the `dpareto` function. Then we plot the histogram and corresponding distributions based on a log-normal and a Pareto distribution. The reason we store the `hist` function is because within this function, there are valuable pieces of information, like `$mids` and `$density`. This allows us to extract the midpoints of the bins and the density at each midpoint. Then we find the values of the log-normal density and the Pareto density at the midpoints. There may be a zero-value issue of some of the density values, so we need to find them in the `trus` data and remove them because you cannot take the `log(0)`. Then you plug your values into the KLD formula as above. As you can see, the KLD for the Pareto distribution in my example performed better than the log-normal.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Vary useful for me. I am curious if I want to calculate the mutual information of the fitted density and the data. Is there any easy ways to do that? Can I regard the fitted one is independent of the data?

Comment: @AegeanT.Wu Technically, the information between the fitted density and the data will be miniscule because the fitted density is a continuous approximation of the data. But yes, you can. I don't know why that would be of help.